# Which layout is better for this database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help with a database table called "Question".  I want to know which layout is better out of the two below when it comes to primary keys:

Question Table method 1:

```
QuestionId (int 3) PK
SessionId (varchar10) PK
QuestionContent (varchar800)
NoofAnswers (int 3)
AnswerId (int 5) Auto Increment
Marks (int 3)
```

In the above table, QuestionId and SessionId are PK (primary Key), AnswerId is not PK, but it is auto increment.

Question Table method 2:

```
QuestionId (int 3)
SessionId (varchar10)
QuestionContent (varchar800)
NoofAnswers (int 3)
AnswerId (int 5) Auto Increment PK
Marks (int 3)
```

In the table above, only AnswerId is PK and autoincrement.  But if if I do that, it means other tables which contains QuestionId will have to link to this table's QuestionId as non keys or something like that.

The database is not letting me do PK for QuestionId, SessionId and AnswerId as its saying that AnswerId is auto increment so no need for any other primary keys.

Comment: You can have `auto_incremented` column as PK, and a multi-column `UNIQUE` index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both cases are not good! You are giving PK's a meaning, but PK's should have no meaning.

Just make your PK a `int(11) Auto Increment` and link tables together with a foreign key.

**Update**

Each table has its own PK. The Questions table has a QuestionId PK.

Tying table together is based on the relation that tables have. There are different scenarios for `1:1` relations, `1:many` relations and `many:many` relations.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `Questions` (
  `QuestionId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AnswerId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`QuestionId`),
  KEY `FK_Answer` (`AnswerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Answer` FOREIGN KEY (`AnswerId`) REFERENCES `Answers` (`AnswersId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Answers` (
  `AnswerId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AnswerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Looking from the Questions there can only be 1 answer on a question (`1:1`). Looking from a answer, it can be used for many questions (`1:n`). For a `many:many` relations you need a extra table.

Here is a youtube doing some extra explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXOj0D80kRg

Comment: I was wondering then that If I make another column and make that primary key int(11) auto increment (lets call it questionIndex), does that mean that lets say I have another table "Student_Answer" Table, can I link both tables using questionId in both tables or does one of the fields have to be a key field?

Answer (score 0):

Normalized:

table sessions:
id

table questions:
id (int 3) auto increment pk
session_id varchar255
QuestionContent (varchar800)
Marks (int 3)

table answers:
id auto increment pk
question_id  (references questions(id))
content varhcar(255)